# Finding the absolute position of the paper/canvas in the Raphael JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, css-position, raphael

How can I find the absolute position of the paper/canvas when using the Raphael JavaScript library?

For instance, suppose the minimal working example is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var size = 600;
        var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById("canvas_container"), 
                                size, size);
        var c = paper.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({fill: "#00f"});
        var x = 0; // get the paper's absolute x coordinate
        var y = 0; // get the paper's absolute y coordinate
        document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = x + " " + y;
    };
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #canvas_container {
        width: 600px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="coordinates"></p>
    <div id="canvas_container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I find the absolute x and y coordinates of the paper from the top of the page without knowing the ID of the div that it lives in? (In the example, I can know that, but my actual situation makes knowing the div ID much more complicated.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. I see what it should be now:

```
var x = this.paper.canvas.offsetLeft;
var y = this.paper.canvas.offsetTop;
```

That seems to work correctly on both IE 8.0 and Chrome 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

To get the abs position of your Raphael paper, you can use jQuery:

`$(paper.canvas).offset()`

Comment: Attention: this piece of code gives different results across browser and its result changes with the state of the paper...

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution doesn't worked for me, it gives me x = -1 and y = -1, so if someone has the same problem I solved it this way:

```
var x = paper.canvas.parentNode.offsetLeft;
var y = paper.canvas.parentNode.offsetTop;
```